# Achieve high throughput for HashMap insertions

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

I'm working with a big amount of data which is getting read from the HDD and put into a `HashMap`. The reading process has been optimized with the usage of `Externalized` instead of `Serializable`, so the amount of the actual data is not an issue.

The bottleneck in this process is the `HashMap<Long, Entity>` which is filled in this process. My code looks as following:

```
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    int nbEntries = in.readInt();
    entities = new HashMap<>(nbEntries);
    for(int i = 0; i < nbEntries; i++) {
        Entity entity = new Entity(0);
        relation.readExternal(in);
        //entities.put(entity.getId(), entity); //<-- Bottleneck!
    }
}
```

Just as a comparison: Reading 4Gb of Data takes **93** Seconds including inserting into the `HashMap` and **14** Seconds without insertion.

Is there a fast way to insert a lot of data into a `HashMap`? The data does not have to stay a `HashMap`. The Map may be immutable, but the access performance is crucial.

Comment: What about dividing the input data and using multithreading over a ConcurrentHashMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison between reading and storing data vs. reading and throwing data away is unfair, because it puts no load onto memory allocator. You can quickly see that by running the following experiment:

```
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    int nbEntries = in.readInt();
    Entity[] entities = new Entity[nbEntries];
    for(int i = 0; i < nbEntries; i++) {
        Entity entity = new Entity(0);
        relation.readExternal(in);
        entities[i] = entity;
    }
}
```

Now that you keep your entities rather than throwing them away, the timing gets a lot closer to that of storing entities in a hash map. Since storing entities in an array is a nearly instantaneous operation, there is not much improvement that you can achieve on top of the timing of the above run.

Comment: You're right, that's it! I've tried to just fill an array and it took as long as using a HashMap. That's very unfortunate. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If @dasblinkenlight is correct (and I think he is!) about memory allocation and garbage collection being the real bottleneck, then you may be able to improve the load times by using larger initial and max heap sizes; e.g. using the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options.   However, it is also possible that that won't help much.

But there is not a faster way to do the `HashMap` insertions.  You are already doing the one thing (in your code) that would make a difference.

Comment: I just noticed I removed the heap increase during my tests. Increasing it actually reduces the required time by about 80%!

Comment: Erm ... that's what I predicted.  With a larger heap, you will reduce the number of GCs.  Since the GCs are copying *live* objects and you are accumulating an increasing number of live objects, reducing the number of GCs should reduce the overheads.  And making the initial heap size has the same effect.

Comment: And making the initial heap size large has the same effect.  The default behavior is to start with a small initial heap and grow it on demand.  But that means more GCs to get there ... and more copying.